# get complete number

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have a script which allows to display search results. Given a query there is a function which is called 'webresultTotal' and it gives me a nuber like'544' With this number I want to do a pagination, so I have li like this `<li class="page"></li>`

So given the number by webResultTotal I want to show/hide the set of li. But Im having trouble when the number is below 900:

```
if (webResultTotal < 900)
        {
          $('.page:lt('+Math.min(webResultTotal/10)+')').show();
        }
```

If the webResultTotal is '544' no li is visible. I think the problem is that '544/10=54,4' Which is not a whole number, so nothing hapens. How can I change the code so that it doesnt get '54,4' but instead a complete number like '54'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to round it up, so you'll get a 55th page.

You can do this with JavaScript `Math`.

```
Math.ceil(54.4); // returns 55
Math.round(54.4); // returns 54
```

You might also like the `floor()` method

```
Math.floor(54.9); // returns 54
```

Take a look at the Math docs: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_math.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use [Math.ceil()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_ceil.asp) or [Math.floor()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_floor.asp).